# react.js desktop and mobile web project architecture

Tags: reactjs, mobile-website

I have really big concern on my web project architecture which will have separate mobile and desktop web app.

I already finished to develop web version based on "create-react-app" project template and for mobile version, I want to reuse my exists web version component as much as possible.

We will serve these with separate url "www" for desktop and "m" for mobile.

I am thinking of two possible ways.

1. Just build another create-react-app project for mobile and share the common code.
2. In exists web client create-react-app project src folder, make mobile version codes like component.js component.web.js component.mobile.js. But in this case I am worrying about the size of bundle js file.

I also thought about the responsive web design, but we have totally different layout and components.

Rendering two different layout within a component by the size of viewport or url(www/m) might be another possible way but it is highly possible for me to use server-side-rendering...

What would be the good approach to solve this problem....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would approach this as follows:-

1. Move all business logic to a common package and use it in both mobile and web. This would make your logic common.
2. Move all the common components/config/colors  etc. to a common package and use them in both the apps.
3. Handle view part for both the apps separately.

   > I also thought about the responsive web design, but we have totally
   >   different layout and components.

   If you have totally different layout and components I would suggest to keep mobile and web segregated. Its not only about the bundle size, you can get around it by lazy loading, but your code complexity can increase.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I think this is the best option.

Comment: could you provide an example on GitHub or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code and build mobile application using **Cordova  Framework**
as your web code will be the one to generate application.

As well you can create for multiple platforms.
Go through official website.
[https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html](http://Cordova%20app)

Comment: I think we will not make hybrid app and probably will go PWA. Still Cordova would be the proper option?

Comment: If you want to generate apk for different platforms using the same code as for web, then you can go for it.